# How can I browse questions with the Community-Wiki status / label?

Tags: support, community-wiki

I would have thought there'd be a "community/wiki" tab among the question tabs maybe like this:
[image: My Image]
<sub>(source: [4micah.net](http://4micah.net/forumstuff/stack/wiki.jpg))</sub>

But alas, no such tab exists. Is there another way to search/browse the wiki/community posts?

Comment: I would love to understand why? CW posts are nothing special apart from community owned?

Comment: I have found that they are consistently more subjective in nature. I guess I'm an argumentative old dude and gravitate toward such.

Comment: I think your missing the point of CW. As for these question on Super User, they tend to be closed very quickly, and if not, will be. CW is explained in detail [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11740/what-are-community-wiki-posts). They are not and were never intended to be used to post subjective questions. These are explicitly excluded from the site as per the [FAQ](http://superuser.com/faq) since this is **not** a discussion forum. Also, questions automatically become CW after a certain amount of edits.

Comment: I don't mean "Why does Windows suck so bad?" type questions, I mean what "Windows OS 3rd party apps can't you live without" type questions. The ones that always rise to the top when you hit the "votes" tab. I like to view and argue that type of stuff and they-being so prominent-probably aren't what you're talking about being closed right away. I find them to be very subjective.

Comment: Actually most of them have been deleted as they are not allowed on Super User. Unlike other Stack Exchange site that decision was made early on, and even in CW form they are not allowed. We don't like list questions. They add no value to the site whatsoever. Unlike what you suspect, we don't look at votes when closing a question, and they are definitely not prominent on Super User.

Comment: I value them. Strange that you bastardize them so cruelly. It is difficult for me to find such information elsewhere with anywhere near the credibility found here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the search help:

> wiki:1 [search term]

You can access the search help by entering a blank search.